# GWT client state

Tags: ajax, gwt, event-handling

I am starting to use gwt and I am having some problems to identify the clients state.

I am using GWTEventService to push some data to the client. But this data depends on which tab the client is. But how to know the state of the client (eg. which is the radio button selected)without using cookies. As I am sending events each 5 seconds, check the client state using cookies to each event that I want to send would make the application become very slow.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you,
Maurício

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different design approach.  Instead of pushing data to the client, have the client pull the data from the server.  I have used GWT-RPC extensively to do this: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html

If that approach doesn't work for you, the next best approach, whenever the state of the client changes, notify the server, so it always knows the state.  You could then to client tracking with sessions.

Comment: Hi Napo, Thanks for your answer. As I want real-time data and I am receiving a lot of messages, the first approach suggested lets the application very slow. I will try this second approach. Thank you! Once I finished I post here the results.